# How to create dynamic size buffer with std::make_shared

Tags: c++, std

I want to optimize next method

```
auto MakeBuffer(size_t size)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>{new uint8_t[size], std::default_delete<uint8_t[]>()};
}
```

As you can see buffer is created in two stages:

- memory is allocated for the buffer
- shared_ptr is created (and memory is allocated for a controlling
  object under the hood)

In general case we can avoid double allocation by using std::make_shared. But how can I do it for dynamic size buffer? std::allocate_shared isn't a solution (if I understand correctly) as a custom allocator is designed to create only object not a controlling block

Edit. Fixed bug in buffer cleaning

Comment: Before optimizing, fix. Your current method is broken (think `new/delete` vs. `new[]/delete[]`)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [`boost`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared_array.html) instead:

```
return boost::make_shared<uint8_t[]>(size);
```

There appears to be a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3641.html) to add the extension to the standard, <strike>but I don't know what became of it. Perhaps it will be part of a future standard.</strike> Update: It's in C++20.

Comment: C++20 has make shared for arrays